# Mysql, php and time differences

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

I have a datetime field in mysql. NOW() gives me 9am and UTC_TIMESTAMP() gives me 2pm. The client real time is 4pm.

There are posts that say I should use timestamp for TZ problems and others say to avoid it at all cost so now I'm confused.

The person who is generating the data (that is inserted to the DB) and the persons (clients) who read it, are both in the same TZ but the server and DB are located elsewhere. How can I make sure that the client will retrieve the date in his own TZ?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with `php` server time zone, `mysql` server timezone and user's timezone. Obviously, all of them are different.

To keep user's original timezone, you need to save user's timezone in database(by location). and convert `php` or `mysql` timezone with that and show it accordingly.

I don't know if is there any other way to do so.
This will help  you to convert timezones: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php

Comment: PHP and DB are actually on the same TZ and now I use mysql command (as I wrote above) only to insert the new record. Regarding saving user's TZ, I tried that but the problem will start when daylight saving changes between the 2 locations of the client and the server.